# Redirect depending on category chosen

Tags: categories, functions, redirect, forms, plugin-ninja-forms

I'm using Ninja Forms and their extension to do front-end posts. They have a function that isn't working that is supposed to allow you to redirect to a specific "thank you" page depending on values from the form (you specify the form field ID). This is the code but it isn't working:

```
function change_ninja_forms_landing_page(){
    global $ninja_forms_processing; 

    $form_id = $ninja_forms_processing->get_form_ID(); 

    if( $form_id == 1 ){ 
        $swapcategory = $ninja_forms_processing->get_field_value( 21 ); 

        switch( $swapcategory ){ 
            case 'Need':
                $url = 'http://dcartistexchange.org/start-swapping/need/';
                break;
            case 'Offer':
                $url = 'http://dcartistexchange.org/start-swapping/offers/';
                break;
        }

        // $url now contains our new success page. Let's update the form setting.
        $ninja_forms_processing->update_form_setting( 'landing_page', $url );
    }
}
```

Field 21 is a custom post type category checkbox and the "case" are the field values. When I submit the form, nothing happens (I get the form submitted confirmation but it doesn't go to the pages specified).

I've tried putting wp_redirect in there (with the exit) and that doesn't seem to work either. Can anyone see what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize the value in `$url`. Test the value in `$swapcategory`. When there is no match, `$url` is empty and that may be the problem. This comment is false:

```
// $url now contains our new success page. Let's update the form setting.
```

It should say:

```
// $url may contain our new success page or it may be unset.
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something, I just couldn't figure out what it was.